# Php explode in Yii2 project

Tags: php, split, yii2, explode

In my Yii2 project, I have data coming from the database column.
In the database column the data is as follows.

```
12

13SeeP

2/3 

Seep2
```

Here I want to explode the numbers in an array

- [12] for the first row
- [13] for the second row
- [2 , 3] for the third row
- [2] for the forth row.

I am unable to use explode to achieve this.I used trim

```
  public function classLabelImdg() {
        $imdgLabels = $this->transportImdg->imdg_sub_risk;
        $imdgLabelsTrim =  trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9,.\/]/","",$imdgLabels)); 
        $cleanImdgLabels = explode('/',$imdgLabelsTrim);
        $classLabelNo = TransportClass::find()->where(['class_no'=> $cleanImdgLabels])->all();
        return $classLabelNo;   
    }
```

The above is doing what i want to but now it is rearranging my data in the array.. I want them to be dispalyed in the same order.

How do  I achieve my result any help??

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add a bit about what you're actually getting instead of the intended result?

Comment: How is that data formatted? Is it separated results (one after another) or just this one with combined results?

Comment: I have got the output now but it is jumbled up.. I want it to be in same order..

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. This replaces non-digit characters with a `!`, then explodes on the `!` character and removes any empty values.

```
$labels = [
    '12',
    '13SeeP',
    '2/3',
    'Seep2',
];
$results = [];
foreach ($labels as $v) {
    $results[] = array_filter(explode('!', preg_replace("/\D+/", '!', $v)));
}
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

the working code for me is

```
$aggregateResult[$index]['lab_number'] = explode('-',  $aggregateResult[$index] 
 ['lab_number'])[1];
```